Cloud run disabling the default URL breaks domain mapping and return 404
Cloud Run recently introduced a feature that allows you to disable the default run.app URL. Has anyone successfully disabled the URL using domain mapping? I tried this on my service, but it's now returning a 404 error.

Can you share how you configured your domain mapping? At the root level? A subdomain?

Subdomain in cloudflare, desactivated the proxy then awaited the cert to be issued then re enabled the proxy

Is it at the root level of your domain or a subdomain (xxx.yourdomain.com)?

Its a sub domain like api.mydomain.com

I tested and I have the same behavior. I reached Google team, I will let you know

thanks @guillaumeblaquiere! also created an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/363140409
